# AngularJS Formdata keeps appending object instead of string

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies

I'm appending to my formdata like so:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('userID', $cookies.get('userid'))
console.log(typeof $cookies.get('userid'))
```

The console log outputs a 'String'. But when it is appended in formdata, it becomes an object (or Vector), as below:

```
MultipartFormData(userID -> Vector(1))
```

Even when I add toString() to the end of cookies.get, I get the same result. How can I get it to add a String instead of an Object (or Vector)?

Comment: Is it only the log output you're concerned with, or does it influence how the FormData is used?

Comment: It influences how the FormData is used. I'm trying to get it in a String format so I won't have to change the existing downstream processing

Comment: What browser are you using? My `console.log` doesn't say anything about `Vector`.

Comment: Chrome. The Vector is what my Scala Play App is receiving. But that's because it's being passed in as an Object instead of String

Comment: If you hardcode a string like `fd.append('userID', 'bob');` instead of accessing `$cookies`, does it still say `Vector`?